# How can I see, control & hear my Mac remotely?

Tags: vnc

Even though LogMeIn has a pro version that lets me hear what's happening on a remote computer, its system doesn't work with a Mac.

So, is there a VNC program (or VNC-like program) that will let me see & hear my Mac?

Answer (score 0):

See [my question on AskDiffent.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7941/remote-desktop-solution-with-sound) The short answer seemed to be: not really.